# How to add datetime.combine to get_context_data in ListView

Tags: django, listview, django-views, django-generic-views

I have next code and trying to add to context value the combine event date and time

**in models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date= models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    evet_time= models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

**in view.py**

```
class EventList(FilterMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
    filter_class = EventFilter
    template_name = 'events/event_list.html'


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventList, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["filter_form"] = EventFilter(data=self.request.GET or None)
        return context
```

need to add next values to context.

`context["now"] = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)`- work fine
`context["event_date_time"]` - how to combine date and time from db table?

Trying next:

```
context["event_date_time"] = datetime.combine(self.event_date, self.event_time)
```

Don't work.

```
 Exception Value:   
    'EventList' object has no attribute 'event_date'
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling self.event_date and self.event_time where 'self' is the EventList view, and not the Event model where those fields actually are.

As you are using a list view, where the contents of the view are based on a queryset, rather than one particular instance of a model, I would create  model method on Event to handle this.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date= models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    evet_time= models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def event_date_time(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.event_date, self.event_time)
```

You don't need to add it to the context as it will be available on every instance that you iterate through in the template, something like this:

```
 {% for event in event_list %}
   ....html here...
   {{ event.event_date_time }}
   ....
 {% endfor %}
```